# is @IBInspectable var did set value in which phase

Tags: swift, ibinspectable

this is my code

```
@IBDesignable class BarPopView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var ft: NSString = "1"
    @IBInspectable var ffPrompt: NSString = "Area"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        print("text: \(ft), prompt: \(ffPrompt)")
    }
```

}

and i set these value in interface builder
ft: 50
ffPrompt: "Change"

but result is print
"text: 1, prompt: Area"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the method `setupView` is called during initialisation and during that the properties have initial values.
If you want to tweak them accordingly , use property observers:

```
@IBInspectable var ft: String = ""{
        didSet {
            setupView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: but i want the func setupView() execute after all the var setting complete

Comment: you can do that by creating an outlet of that view in your custom class and then call it . But remove that setupView method from class initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

If u want the

> func setupView()

to execute after all the var setting complete, Then call the method in viewDidLoad() of the ViewController class, where you will be using your custom view

> BarPopView

Comment: thank you, because i want it called by self, so i set it in key var didSet